# docker-compose "app | Error: Unable to access jarfile "

Tags: java, spring, docker

I'm trying to run a spring application, using docker for the DB, also using docker-compose and dockerfile
I run the command "docker-compose up"
and i get the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTPlU.png)

-exit:

```
   Sudo docker-compose up

   Starting db ... done

   Starting app ... done

   Attaching to db, app

   db     | 
   db     | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
   db     | 
   app    | Error: Unable to access jarfile /customer.jar
   db     | 2022-02-15 12:13:35.642 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.1 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 10.2.1_pre1) 10.2.1 20201203, 64-bit
   db     | 2022-02-15 12:13:35.642 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
   db     | 2022-02-15 12:13:35.642 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
   db     | 2022-02-15 12:13:35.692 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
   db     | 2022-02-15 12:13:35.762 UTC [22] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-02-15 12:13:32 UTC
   db     | 2022-02-15 12:13:35.788 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
   app exited with code 1
```

-my dockerfile :

```
   FROM openjdk:17
   MAINTAINER cristianOsorio
   ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
   COPY ${JAR_FILE} customer.jar
   ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/customer.jar"]
```

---

-my docker-compose:
version: '2'

```
       services:
         app:
           image: 'customer:latest'
           build:
             context: .
           container_name: app
           depends_on:
             - db
           environment:
             - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/customer
             - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres
             - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=postgres
             - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update
             - SPRING_JPA_SHOW_SQL=true
           ports:
             - 8080:8080

         db:
           image: 'postgres:13.1-alpine'
           container_name: db
           environment:
             - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
             - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
```

-my project structure is:

```
ccorservice
|
|-.idea
|-.mvn
|-src
|-target
|  |
|  |-customer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
|  |-customer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar.original
|
|-docker-compose.yml
|-Dockerfile
|-pom.xml
```

Comment: I'd be a little surprised if this setup printed out an error message as an image file.  Can you edit the question to replace the "enter image description here" link with the actual text of the error message (directly in the question, as plain text and not an image)?

Answer (score 0):

Is your dockerfile at the same level as the target folder, because the Docker copy command runs relative to the dockerfile location.